# Spring MVC Jackson message converter: "Conflicting setter definitions"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson2

I have a Spring Boot application with a controller that has an endpoint that accepts an object as a parameter, like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping("/Student")
    public String createStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        //validate and persist Student object
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `Student` object has an overloaded setter method, and whenever I POST to this endpoint I get a Jackson error saying that there are conflicting setter methods and it failed to parse.

I have searched online and it appears the solution is to add `@JsonIgnore` to one of the setter methods, however the `Student` object is from a 3rd party library and I cannot edit it at all.

So how can I solve this? Is there an easy 'Spring' way of making this work? I have played around with modifying Spring's Jackson HTTP message converter but had no success

Answer (score 2):

Use [`MixIn`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature.

```
interface StudentMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore
    void setName(String name);
}
```

And register it in `ObjectMapper` overriding `Jackson` message converter.

See also:

- [Dynamic addition of fasterxml Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290915/dynamic-addition-of-fasterxml-annotation)
- [Jackson conditional @JsonUnwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425419/jackson-conditional-jsonunwrapped)
- [Jackson parse json with unwraping root, but without ability to set @JsonRootName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568867/jackson-parse-json-with-unwraping-root-but-without-ability-to-set-jsonrootname)